# What kind of space is this: $\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{S}_{++}^n$?

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $\Bbb{R}^n$ be the Euclidean space of $n$-dimensional column vectors with real coefficients. Moreover, $\Bbb{S}_{++}^n$ be the space of symmetric positive definite $n\times n$ real matrices. We construct a new space $\mathcal{X}=\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{S}_{++}^n$, whose members are of the form $(\mathbf{x},A)$, where $\mathbf{x}\in\Bbb{R}^n$ and $A\in\Bbb{S}_{++}^n$. What kind of space is this? Could we have an intuition on it's "shape"? Could we define some norm in this space (via some inner product)? Also, could $\Bbb{R}^n$ be seen as a projection of $\mathcal{X}$?

Finally, if we define a function $f\colon\mathcal{X}\to\Bbb{R}$, what would be the following: $f(\mathbf{x})$ for some constant $A\in\Bbb{S}_{++}^n$?

Please feel free to correct me wherever you find useful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you want to do with this space? If you don't want to do anything with it, then these questions don't mean much. Why did you consider this space in the first place?

Comment: It is not a vector space, so the question about the norm is probably invalid. It is a topological subspace of $\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^{n \times n}$. Since $\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ is a metric space, $\mathcal{X}$ is also a metric space with the same metric. $\mathbb R^n$ obviously can be seen as a projection of $\mathcal{X}$. Finally, I don't understand what you mean by $(x, A) \mapsto \mathbb R$.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva, I need this space in order to define $n$-dimensional points that are also described by some covariance matrix. In fact, the points will be the mean vectors of Gaussians distributions with $A$'s to be the corresponding covariance matrices.

Comment: @Tunococ Thanks for the comments.$(\mathbf{x},A)\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ is wrong.. I am going to correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\mathbb R^n$ is convex (affine), and $\mathbb S^n_{++}$ is a convex cone, the product $\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb S^n_{++}$ is also a convex cone. This would be the shape you are looking for. For $n=1$, this is just the open right half plane.

$\mathbb S^n_{++}$ is also a $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ dimensional manifold with tangent space at a point $P\in\mathbb S^n_{++}$ given by $\{p\}\times\mathbb S^n$ where $\mathbb S^n$ is the collection of all symmetric $n\times n$ matrices. A Riemannian metric can be given as follows:
$$
\langle A,B\rangle_P:=\text{tr}(P^{-1}AP^{-1}B),\quad A,B\in\mathbb S^n
$$ 
So $\mathbb S^n_{++}$ and therefore $\mathcal X:=\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb S^n_{++}$ is also a Riemannian manifold.

A good summary of three aspects of $\mathbb S^n_{++}$, namely, convex cone, Riemannian manifold, and Jordan algebra can be found in [this paper](https://www.academia.edu/1015056/The_Riemannian_Geometry_of_the_Space_of_Positive-Definite_Matrices_and_Its_Application_to_the_Regularization_of_Positive-Definite_Matrix-Valued_Data).

Comment: Perfect answer, @Troy, many thanks! Appreciate your help!

Comment: @nullgeppetto :-).

Comment: Dear @Troy, I am back again and I need your help again! There is a very similar question below, could you take a look? I believe you can help! Thanks in advance! http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1296840/on-visualizing-the-spaces-bbbs-n-and-bbbrn-times-bbbs-n-f

Comment: @nullgeppetto I just got back from giving a seminar that cost me the whole week and one final stay up......I cannot respond properly within 24 hrs......I need sleep.

Comment: thanks for letting me know! It would be nice if you could take a look to my question after that! I will be waiting for that! Well, get some rest now!

Comment: hi again, and apologies for spamming in advance! Because of the fact that you are familiarized with this theory, I have also a question about whether is $\Bbb{S}_{++}^n$ with a particular metric isometric to some Euclidean space $\Bbb{R}^m$. The question is below, if you like take a look, and -again- sorry for bothering you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1337454/check-riemannian-manifolds-isometry-to-bbbrn

Comment: @nullgeppetto No problem. But sorry bro, I get my ass on some deadline right now... I will be very happy to try to answer your questions in a day or two.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Whenever it suits you! Really appreciate your help! Good luck with your deadline!