# On visualizing the spaces $\Bbb{S}_{++}^n$ and $\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{S}_{++}^n$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$

Tags: metric-spaces, visualization

Let $\Bbb{S}_{++}^n$ denote the space of symmetric positive-definite $n\times n$ real matrices. I am looking for hints concerning the visualization of such spaces for $n=1,2,\ldots$. I know that $\Bbb{S}_{++}^n$ is a convex cone, but I am not sure how it does "look like". How could I compute the equation of the cone analytically? My idea is to define $\Sigma\in\Bbb{S}_{++}^2$, as 
$$
\Sigma=\pmatrix{\sigma_{11} &\sigma_{12} \\ \sigma_{12} &\sigma_{22}},
$$
and demand $\lvert\Sigma\rvert>0\implies\sigma_{11}\sigma_{22}-\sigma_{12}^2>0$, but then what?

Additionally, is we consider the space $\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{S}_{++}^n$, what would it look like for $n\geq2$? For $n=1$, $\Bbb{R}\times\Bbb{S}_{++}$ should be the half-space $\{(x,\sigma)\in\Bbb{R}^2\colon\sigma>0\}$.

Any advice on how might I visualize spaces such as the above would be much appreciated! The visualization methods do not need to be strictly rigor, any intuitive solution would be appreciated too. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Let me add another question associated with my original one. Let $f\colon\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{S}_{++}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ given by
$$
f(\mathbf{x},\Sigma) = 
\sum_{i=1}^{l}
\alpha_i
\exp
\Bigg(
-
(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_i)^\top\Bigg(\frac{\Sigma+\Sigma_i}{2}\Bigg)^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_i)
-
\ln
\Bigg(
\frac{\rvert\frac{\Sigma+\Sigma_i}{2}\lvert}{\sqrt{\rvert\Sigma\lvert\rvert\Sigma_i\lvert}}
\Bigg)
\Bigg)
,
$$
where $\alpha_i\in\Bbb{R}$, $\mathbf{x}_i\in\Bbb{R}^n$ and $\Sigma_i\in\Bbb{S}_{++}^n$ is the mean vector and the covariance matrix, respectively, of the $i$-th Gaussian distribution from a set of $l$ distributions $\{\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{x}_i,\Sigma_i)\}_{i=1}^{l}$.

I am interested in visualizing $f(\mathbf{x},\Sigma)=0$. I know that the space $\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{S}_{++}^n$ has dimensionality equal to $n+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{n^2+3n}{2}$. I am particularly interested in visualizing $f(\mathbf{x},\Sigma)=0$ in the case of $n=2$. Is that possible?

**Yet Another EDIT**

Concerning my second question (the first "EDIT" above), this is what I have come up with. I am thinking of drawing the $2$D curve that arises when one sets $\Sigma$ to be the zero matrix of order $2$. Then, I guess that I have the projection of the original space ($\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{S}_{++}^n$) onto the Euclidean space ($\Bbb{R}^n$) for $n=2$. Is this correct? How could I denote that? For instance, could I state that I will give the visualization of $f(\mathbf{x},\Sigma)=0$ in the space $\Bbb{R}^n\times\{\mathbf{0}\}$, where $\mathbf{0}$ denotes the zero matrix of order $n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space of all symmetric, positive definite $2\times 2$ matrices consists of all matrices of the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}x & z \\ z & y\end{bmatrix}
$$
satisfying the inequalities
$$
xy - z^2 > 0 \qquad\text{and}\qquad x>0.
$$
This comes from the fact that a matrix is positive definite if and only if its [leading principal minors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Characterizations) are all positive.

Geometrically, this is the open cone in $\mathbb{R}^3$ obtained by rotating the first quadrant $x>0$, $y>0$ in the $xy$-plane around the line $y=x$.  The vertex of the cone is the origin $(0,0,0)$, and the axis is the line $y=x$ in the $xy$-plane.  One way to see this is to note that the first inequality above can be written
$$
\left(\frac{x-y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 + z^2 < \left(\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2
$$
where $(x-y)/\sqrt{2}$, $(x+y)/\sqrt{2}$, and $z$ are an orthonormal system of coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

The intersection of this cone with the $xy$-plane is the open first quadrant.  This represents the matrices for which $z=0$, i.e. the diagonal matrices with positive entries.  Note that the eigenspaces of such a matrix are precisely the $x_1$ and $x_2$ axes in the $x_1x_2$-plane.  Conceptually, rotating this quadrant around the line $y=x$ corresponds to rotating the eigenspaces in the $x_1x_2$-plane. However, note that a rotation by an angle of $\theta$ in $xyz$ space corresponds to a rotation of the eigenspaces by an angle of $\theta/2$ in the $x_1x_2$-plane.

In general, if we think of the space of all symmetric $n\times n$ matrices as $\mathbb{R}^{n(n+1)/2}$, then the matrices with determinant $0$ form some sort of hypersurface in this space, and the positive definite matrices will be one component of the complement of this hypersurface (which can be defined analytically using the [leading principal minors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Characterizations)).  The positive definite matrices can always be obtained by "rotating" the space of positive diagonal matrices, although in general the rotation is more complicated than a simple rotation around an axis.  This rotation corresponds geometrically to rotating the perpendicular frame of eigenspaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Thank you @Jim for your detailed answer! That makes the understanding of the symmetric (positive-definite) cone much more convenient. Would you mind please taking a look at my edits above, as well? Thanks again!

Comment: @nullgeppetto Your second question puzzles me.  Assuming each covariance matrix $\Sigma_i$ is positive definite, all the terms in the summation are non-negative, so the only way for $f(\textbf{x},\Sigma)$ to be zero is if $\textbf{x} = \textbf{x}_1 = \cdots = \textbf{x}_l$.

Comment: Well, yes, you are right! I missed something. I have edited my question, now I think that it should work (be zero not only trivially).

Comment: please let me edit that once more! Here you are! That's the function I am interested in. I made that change because of the fact that for $\Sigma\to\mathbf{0}$ the logarithm tends to $-\infty$. Now that is fixed.

Comment: The expression is very complicated, so I'm not sure I can offer much insight into it.  If you want help with that part, I would recommend starting a new question.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Jim. In fact, it doesn't really matter what $f$ is. I would like to know if my approach (along with the associated questions) is meaningful (see at the end, where I am talking about $f(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{0})=0$). In general $f(\mathbf{x}, \Sigma_0)=0$, where $\Sigma_0$ is fixed.

Comment: @nullgeppetto It seems you have already received your help. Great. Now I shall go back to finish my new Geometric Algebra book.

Comment: @TroyWoo, thanks for coming! Jim Belk really gave an insightful answer, but the second part of my question has not been answered yet (I am talking about the two "Edits" in the end of the post). That's why I have not accepted the answer yet. If you like to take a look at those edits before finishing you book (please let me know about that book, btw! ), that would be great!

Comment: @nullgeppetto This book http://www.amazon.com/dp/1482259508/ I need to understand conformal geometric algebra for some meaningless project...

Comment: @TroyWoo, nice! Good luck with that!

Comment: @nullgeppetto Thanks. I will take a look at your question after dinner.

Comment: Dear @JimBelk, I have also a question concerning the manifold of SPD cone, and whether it is isometric to some Euclidean space $\Bbb{R}^n$. It would be nice if you could help me on that too. Take a look if you like: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1337454/check-riemannian-manifolds-isometry-to-bbbrn?noredirect=1#comment2718059_1337454

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you intend with the second question. This is what I think: we don't really need to consider all the terms do we...$f(\mathbf x,\Sigma)=0$ is equivalent to one of the terms blowing up to infinity:

$$
(\mathbf x-\mathbf x_i)^T\left(\frac{\Sigma+\Sigma_i}{2}\right)^{-1}(\mathbf x -\mathbf x_i)=\infty
$$

One naturally resorts to homogenization $\mathbf x\mapsto\mathbf x/\mathrm x_0$:
$$
(\mathbf x/\mathrm x_0 -\mathbf x_i)^T\left(\frac{\Sigma+\Sigma_i}{2}\right)^{-1}(\mathbf x/\mathrm x_0 -\mathbf x_i)=\infty
$$
being also equivalent to
$$
\begin{split}
(\mathbf x-\mathbf x_i\mathrm x_0)^T\left(\frac{\Sigma+\Sigma_i}{2}\right)^{-1}(\mathbf x-\mathbf x_i\mathrm x_0)=\mathbf x^T\left(\frac{\Sigma+\Sigma_i}{2}\right)^{-1}\mathbf x&=0\\
\mathrm x_0&=0
\end{split}
$$
This does have the geometric meaning of a quadric induced in a hyperplane if you fix $\Sigma$. When you change $\Sigma$, you end up with a family of quadrics. But of course if $\Sigma+\Sigma_i$ is positive definite, the quadric is an empty set so long as $\mathbb R^n$ is considered. I'm not sure how that might help.

Comment: Well, @Troy, I truly thank you for your time, but I need to make just another change to my original post. And this because of your answer... Let me do the edit and check again, if -of course- you still want to!

Comment: Now, after editing that, it's clear that $f(\mathbf{x},\Sigma)$ can be equal to zero, not just in the case you mention above. That is, the coefficients $\alpha_i$ can be positive or negative, so the function may be zero without the need of a quadratic to tend to $\infty$. Well, I know that changes your approach a lot, but what about now? Many thanks!

Comment: @nullgeppetto Now thats really something I am not familiar with. If you take this linear combination of exponential, it should be a gamma distribution. I really don't know how to visualize a gamma with so many varying parameters.

Comment: Yes, that's indeed something else, but let's forget about what $f$ is. What would you call the equation $f(\mathbf{x},\Sigma_0)=0$, where $\mathbf{x}\in\Bbb{R}^n$ and $\Sigma_0$ is a fixed $n\times n$ matrix in $\Bbb{S}^n_{++}$? Assume $n=2$ such that the curve lives in the plane. After all, is this a projection on $\Bbb{R}^n$ or something totally different? I am looking for the right terminology right here...

Comment: @nullgeppetto I would call it a family of quadrics.

Comment: @nullgeppetto On a second thought, might not be suitable to call quadric. It is convenient to fix a constant value for each exponential, then that would lead to quadric in each, resulting in an intersection of these quadrics. Then as you vary these constant values, you have a family of intersection of quadrics....maybe I looked in the wrong way.

Comment: I'm not I understand exactly your two above comments; in fact, this is the first time I see the term "quadric". So, I will look at it! Thank you very much for your time!
Edit: Well, I didn't know in English what "quadric" is... I know that eventually!

Comment: @nullgeppetto Good luck. Its classic projective geometry, very difficult for beginners with modern education background.

Comment: Hi @Troy, I think that you could also help [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334670/show-the-negative-definiteness-of-a-squared-riemannian-metric)! It's about a Riemannian metric between SPD matrices (geodesic distance). Could you help? Sorry for possibly spamming you again!

Comment: @nullgeppetto Thank you for inviting, but I am a little busy at the moment. I will take a look at your question after lunch.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really, I appreciate your help!