# Show the negative-definiteness of a squared Riemannian metric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, riemannian-geometry, matrix-decomposition

Let $\Bbb{S}_{++}^n$ denote the space of symmetric positive definite (SPD) $n\times n$ real matrices.

The geodesic distance between $A,B\in\Bbb{S}_{++}^n$ is given by the following Riemannian metric
$$
d(A,B):= \Bigg(\operatorname{tr}\bigg(\ln^2\big(\sqrt{A^{-1}}B\sqrt{A^{-1}}\big)\bigg)\Bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}.
$$

**EDIT**
It could also be defined as follows
$$
d(A,B):= \lVert\log(A^{-1}B)\rVert_{F}
$$

**EDIT II** I could show the negative-definiteness of $d^2$ if I could write $d$ as follows
$$
d(A,B)=\lVert P-Q\rVert_{F},
$$
where $P$ depends solely on $A$, and $Q$ depends only on $B$. So, is there any way of expressing $d$ as above?

I would like to prove that $d^2$ is a negative-definite function.

For the negative-definiteness of a function $f\colon\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{X}\to\Bbb{R}$, it suffices to show that, for all $m\in\Bbb{N}$, $\{x_1,\ldots,x_m\}\subset\mathcal{X}$, $m\in\Bbb{N}$, $\{c_1,\ldots,c_m\}\subset\Bbb{R}$, $\sum_{i=1}^{m}c_i=0$, the following holds true
$$
\sum_{i,j=1}^{m}c_ic_jf(x_i,x_j)\leq0.
$$

Comment: By Riemannian metric do you mean $A, B$ are tangent vectors of $\mathbb S^n_{++}$?

Comment: I'm used to a Riemannian metric being given as a quadratic form acting on an element of the tangent space.  Are $A, B$ in the above, elements of the tangent space, or is that the geodesic distance between two elements of the base manifold?

Comment: Well, I should have clarified that. $d$ denotes the geodesic distance between two SPD matrices. I edited my question.

Comment: I don't really understand the reason for downvoting... I think it's quite clear. In other case, please tell me what should I elaborate on more...

Comment: I didn't downvote but am slightly confused, as many definitions here are either nonstandard or I lack some motivation.. Is the geodesic distance induced by a Riemannian metric? Is the usual distance function $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ on $\Bbb R$ negative definite, according to your definition, by the way?

Comment: I am interested to show that the **squared distance** is negative definite. This is true in the case of the Euclidean distance: $\lVert\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\rVert^2_2$ is indeed negative-definite (it can be shown using the definition).

Comment: Ok, I see. (Some people may be confused, however, because the square Euclidean distance comes from a quadratic form that is positive definite, not negative.)

Comment: I have made an edit. The distance can also be defined as $d(A,B):= \lVert\log(A^{-1}B)\rVert_{F}$. So, does it help for showing that $d^2$ is negative-definite?

Comment: I have made just another edit. So, I could show the negative definiteness of $d^2$ if I could write $d$ as follows
$$
d(A,B)=\lVert P-Q\rVert_{F},
$$
where $P$, $Q$ are matrices apparently depending on $A$, $B$. **So, is there any way of expressing $d$ as above?**