# Check Riemannian manifold's isometry to $\Bbb{R}^n$

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, isometry

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the convex cone of symmetric positive definite $n\times n$ real matrices. $\mathcal{M}$ is an $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$-dimenasional Riemannian manifold.

Could you help me proving (or disproving) that $\mathcal{M}$ is isometric (in the Riemannian sense) to some Euclidean space $\Bbb{R}^n$?

Excuse my ignorance, please help me figuring that out! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, if it's going to be isometric to *some* Euclidean space, it's going to be isometric to $\mathbb R^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$, because of dimensions. Am I right in assuming that you mean "real matrices" rather than "ream matrices"?

Comment: I have doubts about your claim. In the $1 \times 1$ case, the SPD matrices are $[a]$ where $a > 0$, and the natural metrix seems to be that $d([a], [b]) = |a - b|$, i.e., the standard metric on the positive reals. I can't see any isometry between the positive real line and the real line.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't argue on that... I'm not familiarized with Riemannian geometry. I would love getting some help here, as well as guidance for studying this furthermore.

Comment: Before asking if $\mathcal{M}$ is isometric to anything, you need to specify a _metric_ on $\mathcal{M}$. (The "standard" metric is perhaps the Frobenius metric $g(A, B) = \operatorname{tr}(A^{t}B)$, a.k.a., the restriction of the Euclidean metric on $\mathbf{R}^{n \times n}$. As John Hughes notes, $\mathcal{M}$ with that metric isn't isometric to a Euclidean space even when $n = 1$. But perhaps you're using something like a logarithm to define your metric instead...?)

Comment: Yes, @AndrewD.Hwang. I use the geodesic distance between two SPD matrices, which I define as $\lVert\log(A^{-1}B)\rVert$, or even $\lVert\log(\sqrt{A^{-1}}B\sqrt{A^{-1}})\rVert$. If I used the Log-Euclidean metric, i.e., $\lVert\log(A)-\log(B)\rVert$, then I think that would work. But what about the metric I use? Many thanks for answering!

Comment: Any isometric between two open subsets of Euclidean space extends to a rigid motion of all of Euclidean space, given knowing where one point is taken and how its tangent space is rotated (or orthogonally transformed). But then if an open subset of a Euclidean space is isometric to a Euclidean space, then it is all of Euclidean space. In your case, I think the map $A \to e^A$ takes the Euclidean space of symmetric matrices to your open cone.

Comment: Dear @AndrewD.Hwang could you please take a look at a (very) similar question I asked at MO, concerning the negative definiteness of the Log-Euclidean distance between SPD matrices? Thanks a lot, and apologies for bothering you again... 
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/210736/prove-that-the-log-euclidean-distance-is-negative-definite